# Custom authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm following  [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth#before-you-begin) and for the life of me, I can't figure out what they mean here (Before you begin section):

> Copy this file to your authentication server.

Which server is that? Is it the server where the custom auth system is running or another server in between that and the firebase app?

I thought the point of Firebase was *not* to fiddle with servers. 
Any advice on how to set that up would great.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase create backend services as notifications, remote configs, invites, authentication management, storage, hosting and a realtime database(and some more..) in a simple SDK, so you can focus on your fronted,

Still... there are some services that require a server on your side between those services are the cloud messaging and the custom authentication.

Custom authentication is based on the premise that you already have your own authentication provider, so firebase gives you the ability to connect that authentication provider with your firebase app.

You can easily use NodeJs to create a server to handle your custom authentication.

If you specify what kind of custom authentication you are looking for it will be easier to help you

Comment: Thanks Ymmanuel. I already have an authentication system in place implementing OAuth flow.

Comment: The file they are asking you to copy is a Json that authenticates the server to use the firebase library, so if you have access to your auth server, you can use that one if you are connecting to another external auth server  then you need to create your own server (keep in mind that firebase currently supports officially only java and nodejs in the server side)

Comment: Then you can only use the library to create user tokens every time you user auth is validated by your OAuth flow

Comment: @Ymmanuel So I cannot run the custom Auth process straight from my firebase account? That's what I was hoping to do